# Quaternion does not interpolate by the shortest route

Tags: camera, interpolation, quaternion

I am rotating my camera. I have two rotations, both quaternions.

The big white cube (which I added as refernece) can be seen in both frames, as proof that this rotation is not significant.

from: {0.410, 0.433, -0.557, -0.579}

[image]

to: {-0.004, -0.033, 0.657, 0.758}

[image]

The position and scale are identical for both keyframes.

When interpolating between these frames (using any curves), **the camera does a full 360 degree turn**, rather than interpolating to the target position using the shortest possible route. The rotation was set simply by rotating the camera at a certain keyframe.

How do I prevent this issue from occurring when setting keyframes? At the moment, it appears approximately every 3 keyframes.

Comment: The difference between these rotations in axis angle coords is `(Vector((-0.05185951665043831, -0.9959667921066284, -0.07322026044130325)), 5.055124282836914)
`  _ie_ approximately 290 degrees around the -X (0, -1, 0) axis.

Comment: @batFINGER But shouldn't it interpolate as a quaternion? How can I stop blender setting these values automatically?

Comment: Oops meant -Y.   Do you have to keyframe rotation? tracking camera to a target empty and moving the empty may be easier.

Comment: @batFINGER Yeah, I'm using keyframe rotation. If tracking to an empty is a viable solution I'd be happy to try it.